# Vendoring Python itself in-repos, cross-platform

Tags: python-3.x, packaging, vendor

The majority of our code base is in C++, we rely increasingly heavily on Python tho for our automation, CI, and pipelines. We operate a large mono-repos that is almost entirely run-from-repos - we don't have an installer; our users (employees) run various MacOS, Windows and Ubuntu environments; and run from repos means they go backwards, forwards, and sideways in time as well as having different product/feature branches checked out side-by-side simultaneously. We also have several 1st and 3rd party tools that embed Python into C++ apps.

At this point in our snake-herding adventures, I believe we need to vendor the specific Python version the repository is intended to operate against at that specific version. Increasingly, of late, Python seems to *really* need to be installed though.

We have - of course - tried pip, conda, mamba, pyenv, virtualenv, self-managing solutions, but the key word here is "pipeline": a lot of _sub_process happens and there, when we've almost gotten things to work, all bets terminate. We had a nearly-working virtualenv solution, but literally the first 3rd party package we depended on - psutil - quickly lead to an in-repos wheel stock that started to dwarf even our imagemagik libs.

What we want is to be able to ensure *our* python code gets executed by one particular python interpreter with one particular set of paths and packages anchored to the path of the python code itself (argv[0] / **file** is about all we can rely on), without having to provision and maintain a massive number of variants of the "current" Python build into the repos at all times.

IS it feasible to be vendoring, say, Python 3.10 as a green-install across such a relatively broad variety of targets, and if so what tooling can we use to buy down the management costs, and avoid huge per-script startup overheads of trying to return the environment to expectations?